# Select from MySQL table while ordering by IDs from another table

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

This might be something very simple to do. If so, I apologize. I'm still learning MySQL.

Say, I have two tables:

```
Table1:
`id` int autoincrement primary key
`Name` tinytext
`Phone` tinytext
`Date` etc.
```

and

```
Table2:
`id` int autoincrement primary key
`itmID` int
```

Each row in Table2 specifes the order at which elements should be selected out of Table1. `itmID` field in Table2 is linked to `id` field in Table1.

So right at this moment to select elements from Table1 I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table1`;
```

But how do you order them according to Table2, something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM `Table1` ORDER BY <itmID's in Table2> ASC;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all ids of the `Table1` have an entry on `Table2` use an `INNER JOIN`, like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.itmID
ORDER BY t2.itmID
```

If not all of them have an entry, then use a `LEFT JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.itmID
ORDER BY t2.itmID
```

Answer (score 4):

Select from the first table, join it to the second, and order by the second. Something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1
LEFT JOIN table 2 on table.id = table2.id
ORDER by table2.itmID
```

Comment: Right idea but I doubt `id` is the appropriate join column if it's an autoincrement in both tables.

Comment: Good point - join by whatever is appropriate given the data. If the two tables cant be joined, you can't sort this way.

Answer (score 3):

Ryan's answer is almost right

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.itmID
ORDER BY table2.id
```

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

```
SELECT * FROM `Table1`
INNER JOIN `Table2` USING (`id`)
ORDER BY `Table2`.`itmID` ASC
```